# JHipster 5.2.0, error with angular-fontawesome

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular-fontawesome

Recently i have upgraded jhipster to 5.2.0, when i am trying to create a new project, i have an error when i am trying to run

```
npm install
```

> error 401 Unauthorized: @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.2

And my dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.3",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.5.4",
    "ngx-cookie": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "swagger-ui": "2.2.10",
    "sockjs-client": "1.1.4",
    "webstomp-client": "1.2.0",
    "tslib": "1.9.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please check that your `.npmrc` does not contain `@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/?`

If `~/.npmrc` did contain `@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/`.

then remove that line in `.npmrc`.

Refer this thread : https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/13682

Hope it works..!!